# How to align text based on variable left percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a very peculiar arrangement of two divs that I want to have. 
Basically there is a parent  and a child . The child div needs to be a x% left from the parent s left boundary, where x is configurable. Also, the text within the child div is configurable but the center of the child  needs to be always x% left from the parent 's left.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position:relative;
}

.child {
  margin-left: {x%};
}
```

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class = 'child'>
      Correct Answer
   </div>
</div>
```

for example when the percentage from left is 30%: 
[image: left percentage= 30%]

left percentage is still 30% but the text is smaller: 
[image: left percentage = 30%]

left percentage is 0%:
[image: 0% from left]

left percentage is 100%:
[image: 100%]

Comment: If you apply `margin-left:100%` to the child the whole element will be pushed out of the parent and so the text won't be seen at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - all you need is to apply: `transform: translateX(-50%);` on to the child.

Please see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewONox

Regards

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't seem to understand your question: I updated the pen -https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewONox - what is wrong about it? What behaviour do you expect?